# Only one byte[] from property of items List,

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a List with class `SomeObject`

```
List<SomeObject> list = //fill list;
```

I need Only one array with total `bytes` with the property `chunk` of all items of List

`byte[] allBytes` -> contains `list.get(0).getChunk(), ..,list.get(list.size() - 1).getChunk();`

```
public class BuildArrayBytes {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //fill list;
    byte[] allBytes = buildArray(list);
  }

  public static byte[] buildArray(List<SomeObject> list) {
    int totalSize = list.stream()
        .map(item -> item.getChunk())
        .collect(Collectors.summingInt(chunk -> chunk.length));
    byte[] allBytes = new byte[totalSize];

    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      byte[] bytes = list.get(i).getChunk();
      System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, allBytes, position, bytes.length);
      position += bytes.length;
    }
    return allBytes;
  }

  class SomeObject {

    private byte[] chunk;

    public SomeObject(byte[] chunk) {
      this.chunk = chunk;
    }

    public byte[] getChunk() {
      return chunk;
    }

  }
}
```

Using `ByteArrayOutputStream`

```
  public static byte[] buildArray(List<SomeObject> list) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    list.stream().forEach(item -> {
      try {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(item.getChunk());
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
  }
```

It still seems to be inelegant :(

**Is it possible to replace the `buildArray` method using Lambda?**

Comment: Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `list.stream().forEach()` consider using `list.forEach()`. If the `list.forEach()` is looking bad, consider using ordinary `for` loop, which is suitable for this kind of processing with side effects (such as `ByteArrayOutputStream::write`).

If you insist on the Stream API way (don't confuse with "lambda" which is an expression and a shortcut from anonymous classes implementation) do the following:

```
list.stream()
    .map(SomeObject::getChunk)
    .forEach(byteArrayOutputStream::write);
```

Since `ByteArrayOutputStream` itself doesn't throw an exception, then the `SomeObject::getChunk` does. Therefore, either handle it in the stream (not nice):

```
list.stream()
    .map(i -> try { return i.getChunk(); } 
         catch (IOException ex) { /* handle the exception */ })
    .forEach(byteArrayOutputStream::write);
```

Or handle the exception before passing it to the stream:

```
list.stream()
    .map(BuildArrayBytes.safeChunk())
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)               // Be careful! Filter out invalid (null) chunks
    .forEach(byteArrayOutputStream::write);

...

private static Function<SomeObject, Integer> safeChunk() {
    return i -> {
        try {
            return i.getChunk();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /* handle properly */
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the answer, because I can see what I had not considered.